# Couldn't attach a file on jsp wiki

Tags: apache

I have created a project and added few pages on the jsp wiki and now i just want to add some pdf files, but it shows me the following exception/error

Apache Tomcat/6.0.18 - Error report

## HTTP Status 500 -

**type** Exception report

**message**

**description** The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.io.IOException: Upload failure: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Disk quota exceeded
        com.ecyrd.jspwiki.dav.WebdavServlet.service(WebdavServlet.java:174)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        com.ecyrd.jspwiki.ui.WikiServletFilter.doFilter(WikiServletFilter.java:174)
```

**root cause**

```
java.io.IOException: Upload failure: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Disk quota exceeded
        com.ecyrd.jspwiki.attachment.AttachmentServlet.upload(AttachmentServlet.java:692)
        com.ecyrd.jspwiki.attachment.AttachmentServlet.doPost(AttachmentServlet.java:473)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        com.ecyrd.jspwiki.dav.WebdavServlet.service(WebdavServlet.java:167)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        com.ecyrd.jspwiki.ui.WikiServletFilter.doFilter(WikiServletFilter.java:174)
```

**note** The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.18 logs.

#### Apache Tomcat/6.0.18

I even tried attaching the images but in that case also it shows the same error.

I also have not set any filters on the size or the type of the file for the attachments.

Comment: Have you checked if maybe the service has exceeded it's disk quota, as the errormessage suggests?

Comment: Hey, thanks Kenney for the reply.
Actually i couldn't find the official disk space size alloted to me, anywhere on the jspwiki
so i am not sure that, that's the cause for the exception